# python/genshi newline to html <p> paragraphs

Tags: python, turbogears, genshi

I'm trying to output the content of a comment with genshi, but I can't figure out how to transform the newlines into HTML paragraphs.

Here's a test case of what it should look like:

input: `'foo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nbaz'`

output: `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p><p>baz</p>`

I've looked everywhere for this function. I couldn't find it in genshi or in python's std lib. I'm using TG 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
def tohtml(manylinesstr):
    return ''.join("<p>%s</p>" % line
          for line in manylinesstr.splitlines()
          if line)
```

So for example,

```
print repr(tohtml('foo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nbaz'))
```

emits:

```
'<p>foo</p><p>bar</p><p>baz</p>'
```

as required.

Comment: I'd say this is the best one here. It satisfies OP's requirement for converting an indefinite amount of newlines to a single `<p>` and has the added advantage of being OS agnostic because `splitlines()` separates at `\n`, `\r`, or any combination thereof. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a built-in function in Genshi, but if not, this will do it for you:

```
output = ''.join([("<p>%s</p>" % l) for l in input.split('\n')])
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output specified by the question.

>>> input = 'foo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nbaz'
>>> output = ''.join([("<p>%s</p>" % l) for l in input.split('\n')])
>>> output
'<p>foo</p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p>bar</p><p>baz</p>'

Answer (score 1):

I know you said TG1 my solution is TG2 but can be backported or simply depend on webhelpers but IMO all other implementations are flawed.

Take a look at the [converters module](http://bitbucket.org/bbangert/webhelpers/src/tip/webhelpers/html/converters.py) both nl2br and format_paragraphs.

Comment: I tried using the converters module, but neither function does what the question asks.

>>> from webhelpers.html import converters

>>> converters.format_paragraphs('foo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nbaz')

u'<p>foo</p>\n\n<p>bar\nbaz</p>'

>>> converters.nl2br('foo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nbaz')

literal(u'foo<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<br />\nbar<br />\nbaz')

Comment: The original question is flawed. format_paragraph does the right thing. As one enter in html doesn't means a new paragraph. That said patches and improvements are welcome, the code is really trivial.